# Regex to non-greedily match across multiple lines up to a line that starts with a specific string

Tags: regex, perl, wildcard, multiline, non-greedy

I am going to answer this myself, but this was giving me fits all day and although it is explained elsewhere, I thought I'd post it with my solution.

I came across a situation where I needed to replace some text spanning multiple lines. It wasn't hard to find threads about how to match across multiple lines. My case was a bit more difficult in that I needed to wildcard match any character across multiple lines, until stopping at the first non-indented closing bracket.

For demonstration purposes, I made a sample file that has the features that made this hard for me:

starting file:

```
cat << EOF > test.txt
server {
    abcdefg blablablabla
    pizza
    #blablablabla
    blablablabla {
    zazazazazaza
    }
    turtles
    #}
    ninjas
    blablablabla

} #comments that might or might not be here

server {
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
}

zabzazab

EOF
```

This was my desired output. Note that the bracket I am matching to is neither the first nor the last occurrence of the closing bracket. Its only distinguishing feature is that being the first `}` at the beginning of a line after the start of my match:

```
server {
    wxyz

server {
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
} 

zabzazab
```

What I hoped would work. But slupring with `0777` strips out the markers for the beginning and end of a line, so it didn't work:

```
~#  perl -0777 -pe 's/(abcdefg(.*?)(^}.*$))/wxyz/gs' test.txt
server {
    abcdefg blablablabla
    pizza
    #blablablabla
    blablablabla {
    zazazazazaza
    }
    turtles
    #}
    ninjas
    blablablabla

} #comments that might or might not be here

server {
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
}

zabzazab
```

Matching the line start/end while also slupring was sticking point:

```
~# perl -0777 -pe 's/(abcdefg(.*?)(}))/wxyz/gs' test.txt
server {
    wxyz
    turtles
    #}
    ninjas
    blablablabla

} #comments that might or might not be here

server {
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
}

zabzazab
```

So is there a way I can get a regex to match between a string and the first instance of a `{` that appears at the beginning of a line? I'm open to using sed too, but I figured the non-greedy nature of my search would make perl a better choice.

Comment: You need to focus more on explaining what you are trying to do (mainly in words). I don't know and I expect I am not alone. It would be best to add a precise, unambiguous verbal statement of the problem at the beginning, but failing that, immediately before the line "desired output:" please explain how you wish to manipulate the input data that is immediately above.

Comment: You're right, I was probably still too "in" the problem to explain it well. I have now edited it, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: Better. I still don't understand the rule for matching `"zabzazab"`. Also, is the literal "server {" to be matched or could it be, say "don {", as long as the "d" is in the first column?

Comment: That's true, my example didn't capture all the things at play in my real situation, there were multiple occurrences of `server {` with variable content. The `zabzabzab` was there for testing content after the last `}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps any of following command will do it

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/abcdefg.*?(\nserver.*?)/wxyz\n$1/s' test.txt
perl -0777 -pe 's/abcdefg.*?server/wxyz\n\nserver/s' text.txt
perl -0777 -pe 's/abcdefg.*?}.*?}.*?}.*?\n/wxyz\n/s' test.txt
perl -0777 -pe 's/abcdefg(.*?}){3}.*?\n/wxyz\n/s' test.txt
perl -0777 -pe 's/abcdefg.*?\n}.*?\n/wxyz\n/s' test.txt
```

Output

```
server {
    wxyz

server {
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
}

zabzazab
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. A set of examples like this is exactly what I was hoping to get. I wouldn't be surprised if future me's search finds this exact thread after I've forgotten about it.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the question, you wish to match the portion of the string

```
server {
    abcdefg blablablabla
    pizza
    #blablablabla
    blablablabla {
    zazazazazaza
    }
    turtles
    #}
    ninjas
    blablablabla

} #comments that might or might not be here

server {
... blablablabla
}
...
```

that begins `"abcdefg"` and ends at the end of the line, `"} #comments that might or might not be here"`, provided `"abcdefg"` begins a line after indentation and that line is preceded by the line, `"server {"`. You will then substitute another string for the matched text.

You can match the text to be replaced with the following regular expression:

```
/^server +\{\s+(abcdefg.+?\n\}.*?$)/sm
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/pKj3pZ/6/])

The flag `s` allows `.*` to match newlines. The flag `m` instructs the parser to treat the anchors `^` and `$` as the beginning and end of a line, respectively (presumably, as opposed to the beginning and end of the string).

We can write the regex in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
/
^server +\{\s+    # match 'server {` followed by 1+
                  #  whitespace chars
(                 # begin capture group 1
  abcdefg         # match literal
  .+?             # match 1+ chars, lazily
  \n              # match a newline
  \}              # match '}'
  .*?             # match 1+ chars, lazily
  $               # match end of line
)                 # end capture group 1
/smx              # single-line, multiline and free-
                  # spacing regex definition modes
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I need both the s and the m flags and the slurping:

```
~# perl -0777 -pe 's/(abcdefg(.+?)(\n}))/wxyz/sm' test.txt
server {
    wxyz #comments that might or might not be here

server {
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
    blablablabla
}
```

I still don't quite get why I needed both the `m` modifier AND slurping though. So if someone has a better answer, I'll mark that one instead of my own.

Comment: What for you use **()** in your regular expression? You do not use captured **data**.

Comment: It works without **m** as well `perl -0777 -pe 's/abcdefg.*?\n}/wxyz/s' test.txt`.

Comment: I added the `()` when I was trying to use capture groups to get what I wanted, but I just kept them as they make regex easier to read and they didn't seem to change the results.

Comment: Yeah your way is simpler and better.

Comment: I would not say adding _()_ improves readability, but if you would understand what happens on program level then you would understand that _()_ are computationally is quite _expensive_.

Comment: That is good to know, thanks. I do wish I understood the deeper level stuff affecting performance, but fortunately for me, we live in a time when I can flagrantly waste CPU cycles for personal comfort.